# server closed the connection unexpectedly when pg_dump

Tags: postgresql

i am run `pg_dump` on my vps server, it throw me error:

```
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query failed: server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query was: SELECT
  ( SELECT alias FROM pg_catalog.ts_token_type('22171'::pg_catalog.oid) AS t
    WHERE t.tokid = m.maptokentype ) AS tokenname,
  m.mapdict::pg_catalog.regdictionary AS dictname
FROM pg_catalog.pg_ts_config_map AS m
WHERE m.mapcfg = '22172'
ORDER BY m.mapcfg, m.maptokentype, m.mapseqno
```

Then I notice the sql on the above error:

```
    SELECT
      ( SELECT alias FROM pg_catalog.ts_token_type('22171'::pg_catalog.oid) AS t
        WHERE t.tokid = m.maptokentype ) AS tokenname,
      m.mapdict::pg_catalog.regdictionary AS dictname
    FROM pg_catalog.pg_ts_config_map AS m
    WHERE m.mapcfg = '22172'
    ORDER BY m.mapcfg, m.maptokentype, m.mapseqno
```

So I try to run `SELECT alias FROM pg_catalog.ts_token_type('22171'::pg_catalog.oid)` on `psql`

So it throw me error:

```
pzz_development=# SELECT alias FROM pg_catalog.ts_token_type('22171'::pg_catalog.oid);
server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
The connection to the server was lost. Attempting reset: Failed.
!> \q
```

How can I figure out the problem, and dump my data properly?

EDIT:

Then i check postgresql log at `/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.3-main.log`

```
2015-08-10 16:22:49 CST LOG:  server process (PID 4029) was terminated by signal 11: Segmentation fault
2015-08-10 16:22:49 CST DETAIL:  Failed process was running: SELECT
      ( SELECT alias FROM pg_catalog.ts_token_type('22171'::pg_catalog.oid) AS t
        WHERE t.tokid = m.maptokentype ) AS tokenname,
      m.mapdict::pg_catalog.regdictionary AS dictname
    FROM pg_catalog.pg_ts_config_map AS m
    WHERE m.mapcfg = '22172'
    ORDER BY m.mapcfg, m.maptokentype, m.mapseqno
2015-08-10 16:22:49 CST LOG:  terminating any other active server processes
2015-08-10 16:22:49 CST WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
2015-08-10 16:22:49 CST DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
2015-08-10 16:22:49 CST HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
2015-08-10 16:22:49 CST LOG:  all server processes terminated; reinitializing
2015-08-10 16:22:49 CST LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2015-08-10 16:22:45 CST
2015-08-10 16:22:50 CST LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
2015-08-10 16:22:50 CST LOG:  unexpected pageaddr 0/2AE6000 in log segment 000000010000000000000004, offset 11427840
2015-08-10 16:22:50 CST LOG:  redo is not required
2015-08-10 16:22:50 CST LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
2015-08-10 16:22:50 CST LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
2015-08-10 16:22:50 CST LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

Comment: And what does Postgres log tell you when this happens?

Comment: Hi, @SkyWriter, thanks for your reply, I update the question, and paste the postgresql log.

Comment: Looks like there's something really wrong there: it is either a bug in Postgres, or data corruption, or both, which is causing it to segfault. If I were you, I would: 1) shutdown Postgres and make a full backup of /var/lib/postgresql; 2) start Postgres again and then dump the database on a table-by-table basis, or whatever granularity makes it work; 3) reinstall the same version of Postgres and restore the database again from that granular dump.

Comment: I have the same issue. Its not data corruption for sure. The error is coming for different tables at different time. Any one have the solution for this?

Comment: I tried it multiple times but I get this error after few minutes of running the pg_dump query

pg_dump: error: query failed: server closed the connection unexpectedly
 This probably means the server terminated abnormally
 before or while processing the request.
pg_dump: error: query was: SELECT pg_catalog.pg_is_in_recovery()

If anyone has found the cause of the problem, please share.